# How to call server methods from JS in .NET 4.0

Tags: javascript, web-services, .net-4.0, wcf, asp.net-4.0

I am going to implement some WCF service and call it from JavaScript. Here is explanation, how I am going to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

Is there anything better in ASP.NET 4.0 that has some additional benefits (linked article works with asp.net 2.0 only)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That article you mentioned is about consuming an **asmx** service not WCF.

WCF is the new kid on the block, you should use it. With WCF the advantage is you can return Json (among other options)

Here are some links on using WCF services with javascript/JQuery:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx

Comment: Thank you. But as far as I know Web Service is (can be said as) a custom WCF-service. I mean that it should not be a difference what to consume from JS: either WCF service or web service... WCF service also has a wsdl...

Comment: yes. true. But the article you mentioned is about .net 2.0 which did **not** have WCF, it had **only** wsdl/soap/xml web services (asmx files) ... net 3.0 introduced WCF which is basically is a communication/service-oriented model to implement anything you want-> wsdl, soap, binary, json etc.